# django object is not iterable with custom instance

Tags: django, forms, instance, iterable

I am trying to leave my object itself out of the queryset of possible options. Problem is i get the error: 'Country' object is not iterable
Not sure where i am going wrong.
My view:

```
def edit_country(request, country_id):
    country = get_object_or_404(Country, pk=country_id)
    country_form = CountryForm(instance=country)
    return render(request, 'create_country.html', {'country_form': country_form})
```

My form **init**:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CountryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if 'instance' in kwargs:
        self.fields['likes'].queryset = Country.objects.exclude(kwargs['instance'])
        self.fields['hates'].queryset = Country.objects.exclude(kwargs['instance'])
```

Where do i go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of the method, so you pop the kwarg first. You are sending the kwarg to super.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs.pop('instance', None)
    #all other stuff
```